# How to create DAO class which returns data for JSON in Struts 2?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, struts2, dao

How to create DAO class which returns data for JSON to create jQuery grid in Struts 2? I have gone through documents but I didn't find how to create DAO and what it should actually contain.

Comment: DAOs shouldn't know anything about JSON; JSON should be created *from* data, and things like the JSON plugin do this just fine.

Comment: you need to create json response in your action class not in DAO and declare  <result type="json" /> as result type in struts.xml file

Comment: What it actually contains is a session, transaction, and methods that use the session and transaction to load, save, update, delete entities.

Answer (score 0):

Since Struts 2 abstract from any database implementation, there isn't available any related resources. For integration with any database you can use Spring and/or Hibernate. You can find the simple DAOs in the [Struts2 Hibernate plugin](https://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/).

Also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20022218/573032) answer you can find an article about Generic DAO.